# Unable to connect to apns from php

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, stream, apple-push-notifications

I am having trouble connecting to the apple apns from my production machine, its a vps hosting.

1. I asked the hosting technical assistance and they said that they do not block outgoing connections on any port and that the logs show nothing of this problem and they have no idea what might cause this, so no help there.
2. This works on my local dev machine and the iPhone gets the notifications.
3. `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled in the `php.ini` file on both machines.
4. on both machines `telnet` gives a black screen and not a response like i saw on some threads here.

The code im using is:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
fclose($apns);
```

And the error I get are:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout in test.php on line 116

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in test.php on line 116

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in test.php on line 116

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in test.php on line 118

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in test.php on line 119
```

The last two errors are a given as the connection fails, but the first three I can't resolve them.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: When you 'telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195' you should get a connection confirmation 'Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.'. If you're seeing nothing, it would suggest a connectivity problem causing the SSL timeout.

Comment: The wierd part is that telnet doesn't confirm on either machine but the push get through to the iPhone with no errors on the dev. So the telnet is a symptom but that is non conclusive. Where would you suggest to start the investigation of the connectivety problem ?

Comment: Make sure that your certs are signed and created properly.  I had a problem because my server didn't allow ssl and certificates so triple and quadruple check your php.ini file.  Also I ended up making my own script but when I first started out with apns I used a great script from raywenderlich.com.  http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip
There's the script and I hope you enjoy... good luck.  Sorry if this didn't help.

Comment: Also...telnet gave me huge problems and I had no idea why so this script should be used without telnet...

Comment: David asked that you try telnet to test network connectivity. If you are having issues with telnet, then it is likely to be a connectivity issue, not coding issue.

Comment: +1 for the certs idea fro evan. Without a valid cert you get a very similar error to the one you describe.